# MySQL - slow page load after adding multiple ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, performance

For some reason, after adding 2 more `ORDER BY`, my query became very slow. Can someone help me to fix it? I really need to use the following `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY candidates.user_id DESC, candidates.usr_type ASC, all_users.user_id DESC
```

Comment: run explain on your query and include the output in your answer, e.g. EXPLAIN SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY xxx;

Comment: Somehow i changed couple inner joins for left joins and it does not take long time anymore, never going to use inner join again. edit: only faster with <4 results with more results its slow

Comment: you'd be better off understanding what really happened than making a blanket decision to "never use inner joins"

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you are mixing sort orders, this is very slow in MySQL.
Either `ORDER BY` everything ASC or DESC, but don't mix them.

One solution is to define an extra copy field for `usr_type` that runs in the opposite order.
Like this

```
Example
-------------------------------
id     usr_type    alt_usr_type

1      1           99
2      2           98
3      1           99
4      5           95
```

Now you can define the select as

```
ORDER BY candidates.user_id DESC
       , candidates.alt_usr_type DESC
       , all_users.user_id DESC
```

And your query will run much faster.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: I'd be astonished if that were true!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html 'tis true though!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have indexes on all fields you're ordering by.